# Python - Usefulness of threads with cx_oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

Based on the following context:

- open connection with the Oracle database
- execute one SELECT query
- close the connection

Is it useful to use threads to handle the database connection and query execution?
Does the library cx_Oracle already manage enough to trust its execution?

For example, in the case of the database being over loaded (by other connections), it will keep the connection open undefinetly?
Other scenario case: the query has WHERE conditions, which limit the number of rows. But if the number of rows increase drastically, the query will take more time to execute. Is it useful to thread the query execution, like the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374079/set-database-connection-timeout-in-python).

I have seen that cx_Oracle can be combine with threads for multiple insertions, or more complex software. In a simpler case, I wonder...

Thanks a lot.