# Connection timeout parameter for Oracle DB from python

Tags: python, oracle, python-3.x

I am using the below simple code to connect to Oracle database to execute a stored procedure. But am not seeing any timeout parameter anywhere while connecting to DB or executing the stored procedure using the `callproc` function.

Can someone please suggest how to implement "timeout" in python for Oracle!

```
self.db_connection = cx_Oracle.connect(self.connection_str)
try:
    if self.cursor is None:
        self.cursor = self.db_connection.cursor()
 except:
    raise
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set database connection timeout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374079/set-database-connection-timeout-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

In general there are two ways to stop DB execution after a period of time.

- The Database has a resource manager than can be used to limit DB resources and return an error if they are exceeded.
- you can configure the Oracle Net layer used by cx_Oracle by creating a [sqlnet.ora configuration file](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF006) with various timeout parameters such as SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT and
  SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT etc.  Check the [Oracle Net Services documention](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF006).

For connections, use the latter