# How to check if a command in python script is stuck and take alternative action?

Tags: python

I am writing a script to shutdown Oracle database

I have the below script

```
import cx_Oracle
# need to connect as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("/", mode = cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
# first shutdown() call must specify the mode, if DBSHUTDOWN_ABORT is used,
# there is no need for any of the other steps
connection.shutdown(mode = cx_Oracle.DBSHUTDOWN_IMMEDIATE)
# now close and dismount the database
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("alter database close immediate")
cursor.execute("alter database dismount") 
# perform the final shutdown call
connection.shutdown(mode = cx_Oracle.DBSHUTDOWN_FINAL)
```

In this script there is a chance that "cursor.execute("alter database close immediate")" may run for a long time in unforeseen circumstances. How can make the script wait on this for 5 mins and if does not complete take an alternative action like stop this command or execute an alternate command

thanks,
Tanveer

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the Oracle Net layer used by cx_Oracle by creating a `sqlnet.ora` configuration file with various timeout parameters such as `SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`, `SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT` and `SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT` etc.

You can read the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF006) and there's more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814864/connection-timeout-parameter-for-oracle-db-from-python).

Comment: Hi Colin, Thanks for the reply !!! What if I am using a regular unix or shell based command