# Create cx_Oracle Python timeout on connect

Tags: python, cx-oracle, connection-timeout

I'm trying to get the Oracle inbuilt timeout attribute to work in Python.

Some relevant docs are here:
https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html

```
import cx_Oracle
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("user/pass@thedb")
connection.callTimeout = 2000
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

The trouble is that the initial connection command is the one that is taking an excessive period to timeout (several minutes).

My question is, is there a way to somehow apply the callTimeout before the connection is made? or is there another way to do what I want?

I'm aware of this help:
[Set database connection timeout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374079/set-database-connection-timeout-in-python)
It seems excessive to use threads for this.

Comment: The answer from BetarU on the linked question does not work for you?

Comment: Hi, I would prefer not to have the extra dependency on the sqlalchemy module (which isn'd default). However, I don't think the given example will help as t = threading.Timer(timeout,conn.cancel) call occurs after the connection object has been created. This is the stage I'm trying to sort out. It occurs if I'm in the wrong location, without db access.

Comment: That has nothing to do with BetarU's answer, which simply said: 
"In linux see /etc/oracle/sqlnet.ora, `sqlnet.outbound_connect_timeout= value`"

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I'm using Windows... which shouldn't matter. I tried modifying my sqlnet.ora file, but this didn't help. All three of the suggested parameters set to 1 :(