# cx_Oracle Connection Timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle database but getting below error:

> curcon = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)  cx_Oracle.DatabaseError:
>   ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

Here's block of code:

```
conn_str = u'user/pwd@111.22.33.444:8000/service'
curcon = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str) 
cursor = curcon.cursor()
```

I tried solutions from these two threads but none of them works:

[Set database connection timeout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374079/set-database-connection-timeout-in-python)

[ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970158/ora-12170-tnsconnect-timeout-occurred)

Comment: can you please check are you able to connect db form something like `dbeaver` or some other client.

Comment: Yes, I validated this multiple times as that was my first guess. But it works just fine from dbeaver and doesn't timeout.

Comment: Is database on same machine?

Comment: No, its on a different machine

Answer (score 1):

If the error is occurring because of a slow network or system, you may fix the error by reconfiguring the following parameter in sqlnet.ora to larger values:

SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 0

Your sqlnet.ora file can be found in your $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin directory.