# Increase time before connection timout on python cx_Oracle connection to slow database

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am using a standard cx_Oracle.connect() statement in python like this

`cnxn = cx_Oracle.connect(user/pwd@connection:port/service)`

And I am getting this error

`DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred`

I think it is because we just switch to a amazon/aws/rds database, which is very slow, and the connection is timing out too soon. Is there a simple way to increase the wait until the timeout occurs?

I tried these solutions with no success so far.

[cx_Oracle Connection Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58241993/cx-oracle-connection-timeout)

https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/277

Comment: Answer below but could be any number of things.  Make sure you can connect feom dbeaver etc.  Make sure the syntax is correct.  Sometimes cx will try to connect with wrong details and still give a timeout error

Comment: Yes, I cannot connect with dbeaver either. I am going to look into some other possibilities, but my question still stands as written I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Oracle Client 19c or later, you can add a connect timeout to your Easy Connect string.  See [Oracle Database 21c Easy Connect Plus](https://download.oracle.com/ocomdocs/global/Oracle-Net-21c-Easy-Connect-Plus.pdf):

```
cnxn = cx_Oracle.connect(user/pwd@connection:port/service?transport_connect_timeout=15)
```

There is also a `connect_timeout` option, see the tech brief link above for the difference.

Comment: Are the units in this seconds or minutes?

Comment: This does not solve the problem I am having, but it answered the question I was asking. Thanks.

Comment: The units are seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You probably dont have a timeout with `cx_oracle` but rather with your oracle client

You can `call_timeout` but typically for requests after initial connection.

You can update your `sqlnet.ora` file as below

```
SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 0
```

[Similar so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58241993/cx-oracle-connection-timeout)

[cx_oralce Docs](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html#Connection.call_timeout)

Comment: I tried this solution but I don't know how to test if it made a difference. It did not solve my problem.